Conflicting versions when installing from requirements.txt
I tried to create a virtual environment for the project and installed the dependencies using requirements.txt. But I received the below conflicting message:
The conflict is caused by:
The user requested cryptography==40.0.2
azure-storage-blob 12.14.1 depends on cryptography>=2.1.4
msal 1.20.0 depends on cryptography<41 and >=0.6
msoffcrypto-tool 5.0.0 depends on cryptography>=2.3
paramiko 2.12.0 depends on cryptography>=2.5
pyiotools 0.3.18 depends on cryptography
pymiscutils 0.3.14 depends on cryptography
pyopenssl 24.2.1 depends on cryptography<44 and >=41.0.5

As seen above msal asks for cryptography<41 whereas pyopenssl asks for cryptography>41. I am not sure how to resolve this conflicting dependency.
Below is the content of requirements.txt:
aenum==3.1.11
annotated-types==0.7.0
appdirs==1.4.4
APScheduler==3.9.1.post1
argcomplete==3.2.3
asn1crypto==1.5.1
atpublic==5.0
azure-core==1.26.1
azure-storage-blob==12.14.1
bcrypt==4.0.1
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
bs4==0.0.1
build==1.1.1
CacheControl==0.14.0
case-conversion==2.1.0
certifi==2022.9.24
cffi==1.15.1
chardet==5.0.0
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cleo==2.1.0
click==8.1.7
clipboard==0.0.4
cloudpickle==2.2.1
colorama==0.4.6
colour==0.1.5
crashtest==0.4.1
cryptography==40.0.2
cursor==1.3.5
cx-Oracle==8.3.0
decorator==4.4.2
dill==0.3.6
distlib==0.3.8
dulwich==0.21.7
exceptiongroup==1.2.2
fastjsonschema==2.19.1
filelock==3.13.1
fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
gender-guesser==0.4.0
html-text==0.5.2
idna==3.4
imageio==2.22.4
imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.7
importlib_metadata==7.0.2
infi.systray==0.1.12
inflect==6.0.2
iniconfig==2.0.0
installer==0.7.0
isodate==0.6.1
jaraco.classes==3.3.1
keyring==24.3.1
lxml==4.9.1
maybe-else==0.2.1
mbstrdecoder==1.1.1
more-itertools==10.2.0
moviepy==1.0.3
msal==1.20.0
msgpack==1.0.8
msoffcrypto-tool==5.0.0
msrest==0.7.1
numpy==1.23.5
O365==2.0.22
oauthlib==3.2.2
office365==0.3.15
Office365-REST-Python-Client==2.3.16
olefile==0.46
packaging==24.0
pandas==1.5.1
paramiko==2.12.0
parsedatetime==2.6
pathmagic==0.3.14
pexpect==4.9.0
Pillow==9.3.0
pipx==1.4.3
pkginfo==1.10.0
platformdirs==4.2.0
pluggy==1.5.0
poetry==1.8.2
poetry-core==1.9.0
poetry-plugin-export==1.6.0
prettierfier==1.0.3
proglog==0.1.10
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyarrow==17.0.0
pycparser==2.21
pydantic==2.8.2
pydantic_core==2.20.1
pydub==0.25.1
pyinstrument==4.4.0
pyiotools==0.3.18
PyJWT==2.6.0
pylance==0.16.0
pymiscutils==0.3.14
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyOpenSSL==24.2.1
PyPDF2==2.11.2
pyperclip==1.8.2
pyproject_hooks==1.0.0
PyQt5==5.15.7
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.11.0
pysftp==0.2.9
pysubtypes==0.3.18
pytest==8.3.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-docx==0.8.11
pytz==2022.6
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.2
PyYAML==6.0.2
rapidfuzz==3.6.2
readchar==4.0.3
regex==2022.10.31
requests==2.28.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
requests-toolbelt==1.0.0
Send2Trash==1.8.0
shellingham==1.5.4
simplejson==3.18.0
six==1.16.0
snowflake==0.11.0
snowflake-connector-python==3.12.0
snowflake-snowpark-python==1.20.0
snowflake._legacy==0.11.0
snowflake.core==0.11.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
stringcase==1.2.0
tabulate==0.9.0
tomli==2.0.1
tomlkit==0.12.4
tqdm==4.64.1
trove-classifiers==2024.3.3
typepy==1.3.0
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2022.6
tzlocal==4.2
urllib3==1.26.12
userpath==1.9.2
virtualenv==20.26.3
XlsxWriter==3.0.3
zipp==3.18.0


Please share your requirements.txt

Can you try a newer version of msal? (It's not obvious how it depends on cryptography at all, based on its own requirements.txt, but it's the only thing in your project that needs an older version.)

Ah, the dependency on cryptography appears in msal's setup.cfg (and previously, setup.py) file. Look at those files' histories to see which version of msal is required based on the version of cryptography required by other packages in your project.

Remove version numbers from requirements.txt and try again
share your requirements.txt too
sorry i can't comment yet

You need a newer version of msal; 1.22.0 is, I believe, the first to support a newer version of cryptography:
% git grep cryptography '1.21.0' setup.*
1.21.0:setup.py:        'cryptography>=0.6,<41',
1.21.0:setup.py:            # https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#06---2014-09-29
1.21.0:setup.py:            # And we will use the cryptography (X+3).0.0 as the upper bound,
1.21.0:setup.py:            # https://cryptography.io/en/latest/api-stability/#deprecation
% git grep cryptography '1.22.0' setup.*
1.22.0:setup.py:        'cryptography>=0.6,<43',
1.22.0:setup.py:            # https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#06---2014-09-29
1.22.0:setup.py:            # And we will use the cryptography (X+3).0.0 as the upper bound,
1.22.0:setup.py:            # https://cryptography.io/en/latest/api-stability/#deprecation

The latest version (1.30.0) supports up to version 45:
% git grep cryptography  setup.*
setup.cfg:    # https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.load_key_and_certificates
setup.cfg:    # And we will use the cryptography (X+3).0.0 as the upper bound,
setup.cfg:    # https://cryptography.io/en/latest/api-stability/#deprecation
setup.cfg:    cryptography>=2.5,<46

(Alternatively, you can downgrade any package requiring a newer version of cryptography, but that would likely involve more changes and leave you open to bugs and security problems that have already been fixed.)
